# Как перезапускать slick slider при ресайзе?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Привет!
Использую slick slider, у него есть свойство rows, которое необходимо на одном разрешении.
В итоге когда начинает работать это свойство, слик разбивает блок на отдельные блоки и все ломается.
Решил пойти иным путем, накидал скрипт

```
var width = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var $slick = $('.js-slider-gift');


function initSlick() {
    if(width < 960) {
        if ($slick.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
           $slick.slick('unslick');
        };
        $slick.slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            infinite: false,
            mobileFirst: true,
            arrows: false,
            variableWidth: true,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 599,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    };

    if (width >= 960) {
        $slick.slick({
            rows: 2,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            arrows: true,
            infinite: false,
            dots: false,
            prevArrow: '<a href="javascript:void();" class="b-product-carousel-gift__arrow b-product-carousel-gift__arrow--prev carousel-control left"></a>',
            nextArrow: '<a href="javascript:void();" class="b-product-carousel-gift__arrow b-product-carousel-gift__arrow--next carousel-control right"></a>',
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1300,
                    settings: {
                        rows: 2,
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2,
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    };
};


$( window ).resize(function() {
    initSlick();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    initSlick();
});
```

Решил сделать unslick, но беда в том, что при ресайзах слайдер не перестраивается. Не могу понять как сделать сначала unslick, а затем снова запуск. 
Режим респонзив у слика не работает. Там как раз ломает верстку.

Answer (score 1):

Может так ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initSlick();

    $( window ).on('resize',function() {
    initSlick();
  });

});
```

т.е при каждом изменении размера окна вы заново вызываете вашу функцию инициализации.

Comment: Нет, так же работает.

Comment: @drtvader если возможно вставьте рабочий пример для наглядности (html + js + img) 
Возможно у вас другая проблема

Comment: при resize вы хотите менять то значения  
 slidesToShow: 1,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
?

Comment: При ресайзе необходимо менять rows. Меньше 960 rows нет.

Comment: ДА я пробовал добавить в песочницу. Не запускается отчего-то.

Comment: Попробуйте завести ваш код в песочнице, просто в боевом виде легче найти ошибку, а так просто будем гадать... и ещё, в вашем примере , если вы уверенны что в фунции  корректно работает   " if(width < 960) { " и вы в консоле можете отследить что width уменьшается, попробуйте насильно вставить параметр   rows: 0,